# File Reading & Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()

//Number Analysis Program

{
const int arraysize = 12;
int numbers[arraysize];
int count = 0;
ifstream inputfile;


inputfile.open("numbers.txt");

int highest,
    lowest,
    total;
double average;

while (count <arraysize && inputfile >> numbers[count])

    inputfile.close();

highest = numbers[0];
lowest = numbers [0];
for (count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)
{

    if (numbers[count] < lowest)
        lowest = numbers[count];

    else (numbers[count] > highest);
        highest = numbers[count];

for (count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)
    total += numbers[count];
    average = total / arraysize;
}

cout << "The lowest number in the file is:          " << lowest;
cout << "\nThe highest number in the file is:         " << highest;
cout << "\nThe total of all numbers in the file is:   " << total;
cout << "\nThe average of all numbers in the file is: " << average << endl;
}
```

I'm in an intro to C++ class so I'm fairly new and am still grasping a lot of things. My goal for this program is to read a text file that has the following numbers: 
47
89
65
36
12
25
17
8
62
10
87
62

I then need to read them and store them in an array and have the program display the highest number, lowest number, sum, and average. When I run this program I get the highest and lowest as 47, and the sum and average as some gibberish numbers which makes me think the program isn't reading anything past the first number in the array. Can someone please help me with what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're while loop is incomplete

```
while (count <arraysize && inputfile >> numbers[count])
```

just reads each successive integer into numbers[0]

You'll need to do something like

```
while (count <arraysize && inputfile >> numbers[count]) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! Why is this question rated down? Is it poorly worded or something? Also, I closed the while loop and am still receiving the same results.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but generally people don't like questions that ask "What's wrong with my code?". If I think you're new to the site I'll answer anyways but this is probably a question you should ask your instructors instead.

Comment: @ChaosTheory _"Why is this question rated down?"_ Because it misses the [MCVE] requirement/policy of an on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few indentation problems with your code. I have corrected every mistake and the final result is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()

//Number Analysis Program

{
const int arraysize = 12;
int numbers[arraysize];
int count = 0;
ifstream inputfile;


inputfile.open("numbers.txt");

int highest,
    lowest;

double average;

int total=0;

while (count <arraysize && inputfile >> numbers[count])
{
    count++;
}
inputfile.close();


highest = numbers[0];
lowest = numbers [0];
for (count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)
{

    if (numbers[count] < lowest)
        lowest = numbers[count];

    else (numbers[count] > highest);
        highest = numbers[count];
}
for (count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)
{
    total += numbers[count];
}
average = total / arraysize;

cout << "The lowest number in the file is:          " << lowest;
cout << "\nThe highest number in the file is:         " << highest;
cout << "\nThe total of all numbers in the file is:   " << total;
cout << "\nThe average of all numbers in the file is: " << average << endl;
}
```

The main reason why you were getting gibrish numbers was because you weren't assigning any value to `total` . When you don't assign any value to a variable and try to use it like that, a random value is assigned to it. You must first assign 0 to it, after that you can start adding the values to it.

Comment: Obviously it would fail in such a situation, but it is assumed here that the array size(number of integers in the text file) is known beforehand. If there was no such assumption, then you can obviously use a vector instead of an array, push values to the vector until you reach the end of the file and then use the vector size for the loops and calculating the average. But I do not believe this is relevant here as this is for a starting to C++ course.

Comment: Actually it's not obvious. It would be obvious if you tested the result of `inputfile >> numbers[count];` Your fix actually *broke* OP's while loop exit condition. Bad form, man. OP had that right. You caught the missing increment of `count`. What you both miss is you don't want to iterate from zero to `arraysize` You want to iterate from zero to `count`. OP hands this in, they get a deservedly low mark because the program doesn't work. No one wants that.

Comment: Also, please note that OP used const int arraysize = 12, if you are not supposed to know the amount of integers in the text file, why would he even do such a thing?